# Are CI Sessions affected by network?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have an application, which is written in codeigniter.
I use CI provided session library for session management purposes.
It is deployed on live.

When I connect the application to WiFi or LAN in my laboratory (college) network, session data get unsetted randomly. And the application logs out the current user.

But when I connect it to my hotspot, it works fine.
So I wanted to ask whether the sessions are affected by network type.

Comment: What version of CodeIgniter? I think that up until version 2 the ip-address is part of the session and when it changes, you get logged-out automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After monitoring the logs,
I understood the following points,

- There is a parameter in the session library `sess_match_ip`
- first, you have to set it to false
- then you have to check whether the following loop in session library is getting executed or not,

  ```
  if ($this->sess_match_ip == TRUE AND $session['ip_address'] != $this->CI>input->ip_address())

      {
          $this->sess_destroy();
          return FALSE;
      }
  ```
- if it is, then you need to comment out the loop or remove that block of code entirely.
  I know this is not the permanent solution but it worked for me.

The reason behind this happening is,

Some networks switch ips very rapidly, so if the IP at the time of token creation and request are different, that session is destroyed, according to the code mentioned.

Thank you.

Comment: It worked but I dont understand, even after setting it to false why is it entering the loop in the first place....??

Answer (score 0):

If the IP changes *while you are logged in* and that seems to be causing the user to log-out, it's probably because CI sessions can be configured (or not) to enforce that sessions are tied to an IP address. Please note that while this is easily configurable, if you're using CI's database driver for session data, you'll need to alter the session table depending on the value assigned to this parameter

> *application/config/config.php*

```
| 'sess_match_ip'
|
|   Whether to match the user's IP address when reading the session data.
|
|   WARNING: If you're using the database driver, don't forget to update
|            your session table's PRIMARY KEY when changing this setting.

$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
```

Assigning `FALSE` as the value, will permit that a user remains logged-in even if the IP changes. Your session configuration probably is set to `TRUE`, which means that a different client IP will cause the session to be no longer valid.

If you are not using database as the session driver, all you need to do is change the `sess_match_ip` parameter and  you are set. 
If you are using database for sessions, the changes you need to perform are in the CI documentation here:

[Session Library](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#database-driver)

Specifically, this:

```
You will also need to add a PRIMARY KEY depending on your ‘sess_match_ip’ setting. The examples below work both on MySQL and PostgreSQL:

// When sess_match_ip = TRUE
ALTER TABLE ci_sessions ADD PRIMARY KEY (id, ip_address);

// When sess_match_ip = FALSE
ALTER TABLE ci_sessions ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);

// To drop a previously created primary key (use when changing the setting)
ALTER TABLE ci_sessions DROP PRIMARY KEY;
```

Comment: heyy @javier, i am facing the same issue. I am using ci2, my `sess_match_ip` is false. and i have made suggested changes in database, still i am facing the same issue. One thing i have observed is, my website works fine when connected with networks having ipv6, but unsets the session when hit with ipv4 netwoks.... is it possible that packets are lost in ipv4 network in ci??

Comment: good question, I've never seen that (although that doesn't mean it can't happen). CI2's session class is a bit different than CI3's session library. A quick glance at CI2's documentation says nothing regarding IPv4 vs IPv6 BUT it does imply that the IP address is part of the session data, so there may be some conflict happening there (which would somehow contradict the fact that the session class allows to set `sess_match_ip` to false):  https://codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/sessions.html Can you try setting the session data without the IP address that's added by default?